# Run an command when Flutter app is opened by Google assistant

Tags: flutter, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

Hello is a possibility to detect when app is opened using google assistant. My initial plan is when the app is opened by google assistant it will run a specific command on my app and run that command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[App Actions](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/overview) "let users launch specific features in your app using the Google Assistant."

Along certain verticals you are able to add information to your manifest that will allow a user to open your app to a specific activity with some additional information like parameters.

Comment: [Here is a tutorial](https://fidev.io/ok-google-flutter/) that is specifically implementing App Actions with Flutter